# The basic apps installer extension

Tags: software-installation

I have a question. That is: in windows the basic apps installer extensions are .EXE and .MSI so what is installer extensions in ubuntu?

Comment: As [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/174356/22949) to [that question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/156392/what-is-the-equivalent-of-an-exe-file) says, the Ubuntu "equivalent" to an .msi file is a .deb file. Please note that an .exe file is not specifically related to installation, it's just that many software developers and vendors *still* have not fallen in line with Microsoft's msi-based package management system (which is less sophisticated than Ubuntu's, since it doesn't have nearly as strong dependency resolution capabilities).

Answer (score 0):

file extensions to determine file usage are an abomination.  they don't exist on linux.

most "installers" on ubuntu will have the deb extension, but if it's a script that installs something it could be language dependent.  examples: bash, sh, py, etc.

.run is also common or binary installers.

Comment: Um, file extensions don't exist on linux?  A quick look at `/usr/share/mime/globs2` suggests otherwise.

Comment: file extensions aren't the end all be all on the linux side of the house.  on windows it is.  on linux it's a convenience, but not required.

Answer (score 0):

.deb files are click and install types.
But there is no specific extension on linux which is ready to be run. The architecture of linux OS is some different. Every file stays like a text file, not executable.

More details can be given by professional users.