# Ubuntu/Linux Specific Equivalent of DLL Files

Tags: system

Windows loads `.dll` files on startup to run system processes and load critical features and programs for the operating system.

In researching this question, I found that Ubuntu uses `.so` files and `.o` files to do the same thing [(source)](https://askubuntu.com/a/174356/431864), but these files are used cross-platform and in many different cases - mostly in [C programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809213/what-are-a-and-so-files).

Are there any *Ubuntu/Linux Specific* file types that perform the same functions as a `.dll` file on Windows would?

Comment: Possibly useful : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47208/what-is-the-difference-between-kernel-drivers-and-kernel-modules  (*dynamic link libraries* are not the same as so or *shared objects*)

Comment: @guiverc Good to know. I guess my question has further grounds to it then - if the source I provided was not technically correct.

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9688200/difference-between-shared-objects-so-static-libraries-a-and-dlls-so

Comment: FYI:  I didn't read your source though sorry.

Comment: There are a huge number of shared libraries. Some are written in C, some in Python, some in Perl, etc. They have many different filename types. Typically their package name starts with 'lib*something*'. They may communicate using dbus, sockets, or other methods. It is a rich tapestry.