# Problem opening a file without an extension

Tags: minecraft

I have downloaded a file called MultiMC. I'm used to windows where everything needs a file extension to run. The thing about this file is, it has no file extension. According to the instructions, I'm to mark it as an executable and then double click it. so I marked it and double clicked it and nothing happened. I tried spam clicking it, which did nothing in the end. I'm using the latest dev build of Ubuntu and I know for a fact other people are using this program on Ubuntu as well. I have do idea how to use terminal properly. please tell me what I'm doing wrong and please simplify it as much as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you use a dev build for daily use purposes?

Comment: By knowing the contents of file you may know what the file needs to be ran. just open it by an editor like `vi` or `gedit` and see the header of the file.

Comment: More of an FYI, but Linux does NOT use file extensions to identify files, it uses magic numbers. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/108600/how-does-ubuntu-know-what-file-type-a-file-without-extension-is/108604#108604

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Minecraft MultiMC package requires python-wxgtk2.8 as a dependency. To install python-wxgtk2.8, open the terminal (search for *terminal* in the Dash and click on the terminal icon) and type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8
```

python-wxgtk2.8 has been upgraded in Ubuntu 16.04 to python-wxgtk3.0

```
sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk3.0
```

Comment: Might want to update first (`sudo apt-get update`).

Comment: i tried the command 'sudo apt-get install python-wxgtk2.8' and got '0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.' double clicking still also dose not work. what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I navigated to the directory in terminal and used the command ./MultiMC and recived an error: ./MultiMC: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Comment: Where did you download MultiMC from?

Comment: Here: http://forkk.net/MultiMC4.html